# Large delay between Canvas `pointerdown` and `pointermove` events with stylus

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-canvas, touch, pointer-events

I'm trying to create a very basic sketch pad using an HTML Canvas and pointer events. I've implemented a [very basic codepen](https://codepen.io/cemulate/pen/WNMJzyV) that demonstrates the issue at hand. The key functionality draws a red dot upon `pointerdown` events and a blue dot on `pointermove` events:

```
c.addEventListener('pointerdown', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  updatePosition(event);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(position.x - 2, position.y - 2, 4, 4);
  drawing = true;
});

c.addEventListener('pointermove', event => {
  if (!drawing) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  updatePosition(event);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(position.x - 2, position.y - 2, 4, 4);
});
```

Both when using a stylus (a Surface Pen) or just touch, I observe a large gap between the initial `pointerdown` event and the eventual (good) "stream" of `pointermove` events, as demonstrated here:

[image]

I've observed to varying degrees with multiple input methods on different hardware. Is there a way I can eliminate or mitigate this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `fillRect()` method isn't the best choice for 'live' interactive drawing. The reason is, that the `pointermove` event or any event for that matter has finite precision. That is, if you move your mouse fast enough it won't recognize all positions the pointer might have hit during the movement - it might just be the start and end position.

The usual approach for such a scenario is using the `lineTo()` method instead as it draws a line from the previous to the current position obtained by e.g. a pointermove event. The thickness of such a line can be controlled using the `lineWidth` property.

Here's your modified example:

```js
const c = document.getElementById('board');

const compStyle = window.getComputedStyle(c);
const width = parseInt(compStyle.getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''));
const height = parseInt(compStyle.getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', ''));

c.width = width;
c.height = height;
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.lineCap = 'round';

const position = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
const updatePosition = (event) => {
  let rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  position.x = (event.clientX - rect.left) * (width / rect.width);
  position.y = (event.clientY - rect.top) * (height / rect.height);
}

let drawing = false;

c.addEventListener('pointerdown', event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  updatePosition(event);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.moveTo(position.x, position.y)
  ctx.arc(position.x, position.y, ctx.lineWidth / 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  drawing = true;
});

c.addEventListener('pointermove', event => {
  if (!drawing) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  updatePosition(event);
  ctx.lineTo(position.x, position.y);
  ctx.stroke();
});

c.addEventListener('pointerup', event => {
  ctx.closePath();
  drawing = false;
});
```

```css
#board {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I'm actually doing in pratice; the demo is only to demonstrate the gap between events. In practice, this manifests as the first stroke of any drawing being a rather long straight line (between where the red and blue dots would be, respectively), rendering me unable to draw small or tight figures. After some more investigation I've found that this only presents in Firefox, and not Chrome, so I'm just writing it off as a Firefox quirk for now.